# Problems similar to Borsuk’s Theorem in the plane

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

Consider a 2-dimensional Borsuk's theorem:

> Every bounded set $S$ in the plane can be partitioned into three parts with diameter smaller than the diameter of $S$.

I wonder if there are any results on variations of this problem which consider the following questions:

- partitioning a **finite** plane set $S$ into parts with the minimum of the distances between its different points, larger than the minimum of the distances between different points of $S$;
- partitioning a **finite** plane set $S$ into parts with minimum of the distances between its different points, larger than the minimum of the distances between different points of $S$, and/or with diameter, smaller than the diameter of $S$;
- maybe other questions, connected with extremal characteristics of **finite** plane sets, other than diameter?

Comment: If $S$ is a set of points in the plane, what does it mean for a distance to be larger than $S$?

Comment: Since edits were made to the English in the original post I thought I might as well join in. However, like @GerryMyerson I am confused as to what your first question is asking for

Comment: Sorry for my English. I have edited the question and now I hope it's clear.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if this satisfies the multiple criteria of what you seek...?

> Johann Hagauera, Günter Rote.
>   "Three-clustering of points in the plane."
>   *Computational Geometry Theory and Applications*.
>   Volume 8, Issue 2, July 1997, Pages 87–95. ([Elsevier link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925772196000223))
>
> **Abstract**.
>   Given $n$ points in the plane, we partition them into three classes such that the maximum distance between two points in the same class is minimized. The algorithm takes $O(n^2\log^2 n)$ time.

This paper is lated cited for applications to clustering, e.g., Tetsuo Asano's paper, "Effective Use of Geometric Properties for Clustering."

Comment: Thank you! I had never thought about this side of Borsuk's problem. That's really interesting.

Answer (score 2):

The first question essentially asks what is the maximum chromatic number of the minimum distance graph of a finite set of points in the plane.

Let $S$ be a planar point set and let $m$ be the minimum distance between two points from $S$.
The *minimum distance graph* $G$ of $S$ is a graph with vertex set $S$ and with edges connecting pairs of points $x,y$ such that $|x-y|=m$.

The problem is briefly discussed in [P. Brass, W. Moser and  J. Pach: Research problems in discrete geometry, in section 5.9 Chromatic number of unit distance graphs](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/geometry/book/978-0-387-23815-9). It is observed that $G$ has chromatic number at most $4$, as $G$ is $3$-degenerate. Indeed, for every subset $T$ of $S$, every vertex of the convex hull of $T$ has degree at most $3$ in $G[T]$.

It is also easy to find an example of a point set $S$ where $3$ colors are not enough:

[a minimum distance graph with chromatic number 4 http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/mgfbd.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/mgfbd.png)

See also 
[G. Csizmadia, On the Independence Number of Minimum Distance Graphs](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/PL00009381.pdf) for a related problem of finding large independent sets in $G$.